# Jacada Extension - Unable to assign variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign a system variable in jacada extension, but its not assigned.

Please help....

```
initExtensions("sample", function(app) {
  //varTest is a system variable 
  app.registerExtension("loaded", function(ctx, page) {
    var txt_var = "test123";
    ctx.setVariable('varTest', txt_var);
    ctx.getVariable('varTest', function(data3) {
      //success
      console.log('Op:', data3);
    }, function(xhr3) {
      console.log('Fail');
    });
  });

  app.registerExtension('pageRenderer', function(ctx, page) {
    // Place your extension code here                
    return page;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Xavier, variables only get set once when the end user clicks Next or Done.

See here: [Using Interaction Variables in Application Extensions](https://jacada.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205481635-Using-Interaction-Variables-in-Application-Extensions)

<sub>* Disclaimer: I work for Jacada</sub>